# JSON - json_encode not formating properly foreach loop

Tags: php, json

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?PHP


$url = 'http://www.sportsdirect.com/dunlop-mens-canvas-low-top-trainers-246046?colcode=24604622';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $DataVariants = $xpath->query('//span[@class="ImgButWrap"]/@data-variants')->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $jsonStart = strpos($DataVariants, '[');
    $jsonEnd = strrpos($DataVariants, ']');

    $collections = json_decode(substr($DataVariants, $jsonStart, $jsonEnd - $jsonStart + 1));   


    $result = array();

    foreach ($collections as $item) {
        $ColVarId = $item->ColVarId;


        $SizeNames = [];
        foreach ($item->SizeVariants as $size) {
            $SizeNames[] = $size->SizeName;
        }

        if (in_array("7", $SizeNames)) {
            $result[]['colorids'] = $ColVarId;              
        }

    }

    echo json_encode($result);  


?>
```

Echo prints this:

```
[{"colorids":"24604603"},{"colorids":"24604684"},{"colorids":"24604640"},{"colorids":"24604609"},{"colorids":"24604682"},{"colorids":"24604686"},{"colorids":"24604681"},{"colorids":"24604689"},{"colorids":"24604602"},{"colorids":"24604679"},{"colorids":"24604680"},{"colorids":"24604622"},{"colorids":"24604685"},{"colorids":"24604683"},{"colorids":"24604621"},{"colorids":"24604677"},{"colorids":"24604688"}]
```

The desired output format is

```
{"colorids": ["id1","id2","id3","id4","id5","id6","id7","id8"] }
```

In hours i can not understand where is my mistake. Can you help me out resolve this because i think the echo result is not correct one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In which format do you want the data?

Comment: Like `{"colorids":"id1","id2","id3","id4","id5","id6","id7","id8"}`

Comment: `{"colorids":"id1","id2","id3","id4","id5","id6","id7","id8"}` That's not valid JSON. Do you mean `{"colorids": ["id1","id2","id3","id4","id5","id6","id7","id8"] }`?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Also you could just have edited your original question instead of reposting.

Comment: Yes @VolkerK that is what i want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code creates an array of arrays

```
if (in_array("7", $SizeNames)) {
   $result[]['colorids'] = $ColVarId;              
}
```

to,

```
if (in_array("7", $SizeNames)) {
        $result['colorids'][] = $ColVarId;              
}
```

output

```
{"colorids":["id1","id2","id3","id4","id5","id6","id7","id8"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result[]['colorids']
```

From json_encode's point of view here you are adding a new object that has the property `colorids` to an array. But you want one object that has a property `colorids` that is an array of strings (more or less the other way round):

```
$result = array( 'colorids'=>array() );
...
$result['colorids'][] = $ColVarId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
if (in_array("7", $SizeNames)) {
        $result['colorids'][] = $ColVarId;              
}
```

to get the such output

```
{"colorids":["id1","id2","id3","id4","id5","id6","id7","id8"]}
```